# How to get Knockout to read value from hidden input

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form with a hidden input in my MVC application whose value I want read by Knockout.  Unfortunately the observable function in Knockout REPLACES the original value in the DOM with whatever value is specified within the parenthesis so that

```
self.title = ko.observable()
```

changes the value of the hidden input to blank.  This would not be so bad if I had a blank form that the user needed to fill.  I found some answers on Stackoverflow that use complicated custom binding, but I simply refuse to believe that something THIS simple requires such a complicated solution. Does Knockout have a native way to either:

1. Read the EXISTING value of inputs from the DOM
2. Bind the EXISTING values without first replacing them with an
   initial value?

Here is the DOM:

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
                <input type="hidden" id="title" value="@RazorFunction('Title')" data-bind="value:title" />
                <label class="control-label" for="message">@RazorFunction('Label')</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="@RazorFunction('Placeholder')" rows="5" cols="50" data-bind="value:message"></textarea>
                <br />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:sendMessage">@RazorFunction('Send')</button>
            </div>
```

Here is my model in .js file:

```
var Model = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.message = ko.observable("")
        self.title = ko.observable()
        self.messages = ko.observableArray()
    };
```

Comment: In your model set `self.title = ko.observable(@RazorFunction('Title'))`. That's what I did to work around that issue. There's no getting around the overwrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just completely ignore the hidden input and provide this value as initial value to your view model.

```
var init = {title: 'foo'};
var Model = function(initial){
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(initial.title);
    // ...
};
var vm = new Model(init);
```

If it's really necessary to keep this hidden input, you could try getting it's value before the viewmodel initialization happens.

```
var init = {};
init.title = document.getElementById('title').value;
ko.applyBindings(new Model(init));
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  This worked, thank you.  I was pulling my non-existent hair out over this.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a form with a hidden input in my MVC application whose value I want read by Knockout.

This is entirely the wrong thing to want. Knockout *generates* a user interface (i.e. the view) from a model, it does not generate a model from a user interface.

> Unfortunately the observable function in Knockout REPLACES the original value in the DOM with whatever value is specified within the parenthesis so that

That's exactly what is supposed to happen. The user interface reflects what the model dictates.

The issue here is: Why do you have parts of a view that don't correspond with your data model? Correct this and the problem will dissolve.

A hidden input with a value is an entirely unnecessary thing for a knockout-based application. If the server knows a value that it needs to transport to the client, don't have it written into the HTML. Create/send JSON that contains all values your model needs for initialization, let Knockout do the entire UI creation, resist the urge to create dynamic UI with Razor views.

Here's what the view should look like (let Razor do the internationalization, that's fine):

```html
<div class="form-group has-success">
  <!-- title is already part of the model, no need to put it in the view
       unless it actually shows up anywhere -->
  <label class="control-label" for="message">@RazorFunction('Label')</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="@RazorFunction('Placeholder')" rows="5" cols="50" data-bind="value:message"></textarea>
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:sendMessage">@RazorFunction('Send')</button>
</div>
```

and the viewmodel:

```
var Model = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.message = ko.observable(data.message)
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title)
    self.messages = ko.observableArray(data.messages);
};
```

where `data` is an object with the initial values.